# Decrypted RSA 64 bit encryption using modulus and private exponent. Got gobbledygook [Verify]

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key, openssl, file-encryption

As part of an experiment, I was given a .enc RSA (encrypted) file that was most likely generated using openssl. I had the public key, I factored it, obtained the private exponent, and decrypted the .enc file in chunks of 64 bit. What I got as a result, was nonsense hex. I was supposed to get a password or secret key.

**What I have so far:**

```
 Factors: 3917781347 x 4215069449 
 Private exponent: 9440767265896423601
 Modulus: 16513720463601767803
```

I have used xxd to extract the hex data from the ciphertext file: `xxd -p > enc.hex`

This created a hex dump of the file called 'enc.hex'. The contents of this file begin like this:

```
 7d4554292d7b9f980ed049cea0f968cf438b6fc312cf2028ce5ce2fe9f38
 387b72a01bf6564f25884a2cacd187c2eeccd0cf78c2a74785f18d5e72b5
 270ac3e45b6f7505347b38ec7684b1af206d73ea4a84cd59b50be56d7abf
 74a569868406ab2b17846c9e448fe1392b21dac0b10fbb733536c99e598b
 683be7400a1ad55c42faa171becd803b8b8f4a1fa512a33222ec042486c5
 672f6200d4f00e2994b6d247a44edb6ce90795bde7ccda4433cf6fca8362
 f87c68f9df6418c4f0b8fb9da39a1d173fea2b1466e646f01e2dc7fb0499
 311d35ec75c15c5910b2d3e0c662de0b3b1716bab44faa2a36538bb44f6a
 3c3abd37692cf95fa075b58485ad983533782d7bf51e10c0e3b18ccec972
```

**My Python code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
d = 9440767265896423601
N = 16513720463601767803

file = open('enc.hex', 'r')
c = file.read()
n = 16
c = c.replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '')
m = [hex(pow(int(c[i:i+n], 16), d, N)).rstrip("L") for i in range(0, len(c), n)]


f = open('decrypted.hex', 'w')
f.write(''.join(m))
f.close()
```

Where, 'c' is the ciphertext, 'd' is the private exponent, 'N' is the modulus and 'm' is supposed to contain the plaintext hex bytes.

**Output of my python script:**

```
  0x2f2f7656414141410x41414141615155410x41416741414130670x6f414142464a4636
  0x39746d3641414b530x4c3137624e3041410x41424a44414141410x412f365758484676
```

When I convert this to ASCII, I get nonsense:

`//vVAAAAAAAAaQUAAAgAAA0goAABFJF69tm6AAKSL17bN0AAABJDAAAAA/6WXHFv`

Also, '2F 2F' is not a Magic Number and does not indicate a file type. As I said, I was supposed to get a password one way or another after decryption.

I have spent weeks over this experiment, and I'm on the verge of crying now if I don't decrypt this and get the password to the next level.

Could someone please quickly verify what I've done is right, and they are getting the same hex sequence after decryption? Here are the files in a tarball:

http://www.filedropper.com/chaltar

Contents:

- .enc encrypted file
- .uyu (was a hint that .enc is encrypted in RSA 64 bit chunks; you can ignore it)
- .pem (a public key from where I extracted the modulus and public exponent)

**UPDATE:**

I understand what I need to do now, and I know what to expect. However, my Python code seems to be messing up the 64 bit block decryption somewhere near the end as I'm not getting the two '==' signs (3d 3d) at the end after decryption. This is the trail (end) hexdump of my decrypted file:

```
   002ACD50  33 30 34 31  34 31 34 31   34 31 34 31  30 78 34 31   3041414141410x41
   002ACD60  34 31 34 31  34 31 34 31   34 31 34 31  34 31 30 78   414141414141410x
   002ACD70  34 31 34 31  34 31 34 31   34 31 34 31  34 31 34 31   4141414141414141
   002ACD80  30 78 35 61  35 31 33 64   33 64 34 31  34 31 34 31   0x5a513d3d414141
   002ACD90  34 31 30 78  30                                       410x0
```

The file unexpectedly ended with one byte (30). Could someone point out what is wrong with my python decryption code above?

Comment: Did you try to bsse64 decode this to binary?

Comment: The = signs at the end are not necessary so try it anyway

Comment: Write to file using > outputfile then do hd outputfile to see hex dump

Comment: And hd shows what? File output says nothing

Comment: There should be more than 00's at the start from the //vV characters

Comment: You are doing it right but perhaps there's a bug or a minor problem along the way. Note that your ciphertext is around 1.2 Mb long, so your plaintext (after RSA decryption) should be of the same size. Once you'll get this, decode the result with base 64 (you may need to pay attention to the end of the file, depending on how picky your base64-decoding tool is) and you'll end up with a playable MP3 file indeed. I am deliberately not posting source code as to not spoil your fun :)

Comment: Yes, it contains synthetic voice that will give you the password you're looking for :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question isn't really about cryptography, the problem was due to non-cryptographic issues.

Comment: Please don't destroy your posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the procedure myself, and I can confirm that base64 decoding will do the trick; the full decrypted file will have == at the end somewhere. After decoding, the "file" command will reveal the plain text type. The '.uyu' file is quite easy to "decrypt" as well, I noted.

Comment: Remove the final 0x0. And also the final 4 41's (A's) as well, which are probbaly padding to fill out a block. The == (3d3d) are before that and are the end of the proper base64